# emailauthor page parameter from (p26) not working

Tags: visualforce, email, custom-button

I am trying to send an email from the emailauthor page (Activity History Send Email), when I get into the page I have multiple options to select in the field From, I want to always have a default value, so I have created a button and the parameter p26 with the value that I want, having an URL looking like this:

https://cs31.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid=001p0000003ajeV&rtype=003&p3_lkid=006p000000247ci&retURL=%2F006p000000247ci&p26="From Name" <myemailfrom@gmail.com>

This is showing up this value in the From field but when the email is sent, even that this value is the selected one, it still been sent by other value.
[image]

I am not sure if there is somewhere in the set up that I can default this, or if it is something wrong with my parameter, I have tried different options but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the exact option value, meaning you have to know up to three things: The custom ID associated with the email (e.g. for organization-wide addresses), the email being sent from, and the display name. I tried this in my organization, and I came up with a URL that looks like this:

```
https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p26=0D2XXXXXXXXXXXX:username@emaildomain:Display%20Value
```

Obviously, *my* specific details have been left out, but the principle remains the same. Please note that, as always, URL hacking is not supported, and this may change at any time, so code you write today might not be valid in a few months, especially during this time of migration from Classic to Lightning. However, for whatever time is left that this may work, try selecting your drop down, then using the DOM Inspector for your browser to find the appropriate option value, then use that to populate the link. The code will look like this:

```
<select id="p26" name="p26">
    <option value="username@emaildomain:User%20Full%20Name" selected="selected">"User Full Name" &lt;username@emaildomain&gt;</option>
    <option value="0D2XXXXXXXXXXXX:username2@emaildomain2:Display%20Name">"Display Name" &lt;username2@emaidomain2&gt;</option>
</select>
```

You need to use the *exact* value as specified in the value attribute in order for the appropriate value to be selected.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, ideally I dont want to use it in the URL, but I couldnt find the way to set one of the email as a default, is there somewhere that I need to look or adding this param in the URL is the only way?

Comment: @manza Apparently there's [this feature](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_case_feed_default_email_fields.htm), the [QuickActionDefaultsHandler Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_QuickAction_QuickActionDefaultsHandler.htm), but it only works for cases. There's still an idea pending for the ability to hook into the email author page correctly in all contexts. A URL hack is (sadly) probably your best choice.